# Custom Brush Only Affects One Area

Tags: transforms, sculpting, multiresolution

I'm trying to make scales on an object, but only certain areas of the object are affected by the brush. I'm trying to make a snake, so started with a cylinder, blocked out a shape, then used a multi-res modifier to add resolution. I made an alpha in photoshop that's basically a gradient over a white circle to black and brought that into blender as a texture. However, when I try to use this brush only certain areas are affected.[image]

[image]

I've tried to applying all transforms, applying the modifiers then using dynotopo, not using multires and just using dynotopo, and just using multires as a modifier without applying transforms. Not sure how to get this to work. Any help would be appreciated.